# Failed to invoke the service. Possible causes: The service is offline or inaccessible; Relations in tables

Tags: c#, sql-server, wcf, entity-framework-6, edmx

I came across a weird situation in WCF Service. I don't know what exactly the reason behind this. The screen shots are self explanatory.

Below screen shots shows - 1. Project structure, 2. DB Structure, 3. Table relations etc.
[image: Tables]
[image: Table Relations]
[image: Project Structure]
[image: EDMX Models]
[image: Interface]
[image: Implementation]

Now closely observe the result i got -

[image: Result1]
[image: Result2]

This is weird. I don't understand why WCF generating error here.

Later on I have done some R&D and removed the relation between tables.

[image: Relation Removed]
[image: Relation Removed from EDMX]

Now see the result - 
[image: Result3]

Surprisingly, the WCF is functioning. 
This is really weird. 
Can anybody explain me why this behavior, and what changes should i make to make my service working with relational tables.

Thank you for sharing your time and wisdom.

Comment: Have you tried creating your own client? WCF Test Client is limited in what it can do.

Comment: Yes, i did. Getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing this with code first, write it into the context in constructor

```
Base.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
```